# Is there a way to reewrite postgresql selects to include multiple table records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I'm working with a multi-tenant application that has one schema per company using postgreSQL, each company can only access its own schema, but we also have a admin company that should see the data from all the other companies.

Example:

## **company1.table**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

## **company2.table**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

## **admin.table**

| Column A | Column B | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | 1 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | 2 |

I want the ORM to select from admin.table directly but with some intermediate step that could iterate all schemas replacing the current_query() to reference each schema and then applying 'union all' in the end of each iteration.

I tried using views but things started to get extremely slow due to indexing lost, same thing with **inherited** tables

I also tried materialized views, but by doing that i'm not able to create triggers for insertion.

If there is a way of doing this, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Have you tried making `admin.table` a [partitioned](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) table and attaching `companyN.tables` to it, after adding a `company_id` column to them? Tweaking your [parallel worker](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/how-parallel-query-works.html) settings could help as well

Comment: `UNION ALL` is the way to go. Perhaps you could ask a question about a concrete query that performs badly.